# Calculating the value given by an infinite converging series

Tags: calculus

$0<p<1$

$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} k (1 - p)^{k-1}$

How'd I go by calculating this?

Comment: The formula for $\sum_k kx^k$ and the likes of it has been asked a considerable number of dozens of times on this site. Search for it.

Comment: You know that $\sum_{k=0}^\infty(1-p)^{k}=\frac{1}{p}$. Consider differentiating both sides in $p$.